# Check box inside repeater , How to get command name value in the check changed function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5

HI i have above html tag in my asp.net listview item template ,

```
<td> 
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkStudentStatus"  Text='<%# GetStatusString(Eval("StudentStatus").ToString()) %>' CommandName='<%#Eval("StudentID")%>' OnCheckedChanged="chkStudentStatus_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%#Eval("StudentStatus") %>'  AutoPostBack="True" />
</td>
```

While check box value changed i was to get the Command Name value in the " chkStudentStatus_CheckedChanged " function

Answer (score 9):

try this:

Short and simple

**[Refrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkeesb2c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

your check box

```
<td> 
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkStudentStatus"  Text='<%# GetStatusString(Eval("StudentStatus").ToString()) %>' CommandName='<%#Eval("StudentID")%>' OnCheckedChanged="chkStudentStatus_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%#Eval("StudentStatus") %>'  AutoPostBack="True" />
</td>
```

in code behind

```
protected void chkStudentStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    var studentID = chk.Attributes["CommandName"];


}
```

you can give any named attribute i.e. **xyz='<%#Eval("StudentID")%>'**

than 
in code behind

```
protected void chkStudentStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    var studentID = chk.Attributes["xyz"];


}
```

Comment: This works but keep in mind the data added to the Attributes collection will get rendered in the wrapper <span> tag. If you want to append the property to the check box itself, you have to use InputAttributes instead of Attributes

Answer (score -1):

```
var item = (RepeaterItem) sender.NamingContainer;
```

change with:

```
var item = (RepeaterItem) chk.NamingContainer;
```