# edit item inline client side using jquery and webservice

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web-services, webmethod

```html
   <script>
        function validate() {
            var editName = document.getElementById('<%=txt_editName.ClientID %>').value;
            var editPrice = document.getElementById('<%=txt_editPrice.ClientID %>').value;
            if (editName == "") {
                alert("Enter  Name");
                return false;
            }
            if (editPrice == "" && editPrice.value != 0) {
                alert("Enter  Price");
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_serchName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SearchPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_search" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btn_search_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        Add/Edit:<br />
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_editName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_editPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_saveItems" OnClientClick="return validate()" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_success" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <p>
            &nbsp;
        </p>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="S.No." />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" />

                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

i want to make webservice that i can update the price at client side with jquery and webservice .ability to edit the price inline (clientside using jquery and webservice)

```
    public partial class Items_Page : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{
    String conctiioon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopcart"].ConnectionString;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gvbind();
    }
}
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopcart"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        con.Open();
        if (txt_serchName.Text == "" && txt_SearchPrice.Text == "")
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "Select * from items";
            comm.Connection = con;
            GridView2.DataSource = comm.ExecuteReader();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }

        if (txt_serchName.Text.Length > 0 && txt_SearchPrice.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            com.CommandText = "SearchItemByName_Price";
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Connection = con;
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", txt_serchName.Text));
            GridView2.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
            GridView2.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlTransaction tran = null;
    try
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopcart"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
        {

            com.CommandText = "Insert_EditItems";
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Connection = con;
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", txt_editName.Text));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", txt_editPrice.Text));
            con.Open();
            tran = con.BeginTransaction();
            com.Transaction = tran;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tran.Commit();
            lbl_success.Text = "Record inserted successfully";
        }

        SqlCommand com_ = new SqlCommand();
        com_.CommandText = "Select * from items";
        com_.Connection = con;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = com_;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        lbl_success.Text = "You Can not save this item ";
    }

    if (Session["rowid"]!=null)
    {

    }
}
protected void gvbind()
{
    String conction = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopcart"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conction);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from items";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        int columncount = GridView2.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        GridView2.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        GridView2.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
        GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    }

}
protected void displayRowIndex() 
{
    //int rowid= Session["rowid"].ToString();
}
protected void GridView2_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    gvbind();
}
//protected void rowid(int id)
//{
//    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conctiioon);
//    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from items where id ="+id,con);
//    cmd.Connection = con;
//    cmd.ExecuteReader();


//}
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Session["rowid"] = e.NewEditIndex;
    //int idd=int.Parse( Session["rowid"].ToString());
    //rowid(idd);
    gvbind();
}
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conctiioon);
    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
    TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox textprice = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    conn.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail", conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update items set name='" + textName.Text + "',price='" + textprice.Text + "' where id='" + userid + "'", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    gvbind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conctiioon);
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Label lbldeleteid = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete FROM items where id='" + Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()) + "'", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    gvbind();
}
```

}

Comment: Then what you would need is Ajax, which would return you a collection in which you could manipulate with the data client side.  Expand with additional Ajax to modify the price, updated for instance.

Comment: i don't understand you clearly

Comment: You would pass a value or object through Ajax, then your web-service would deserialize said value or object.  Then you run the query with that data, then on success, it will return a response back to your Ajax as an object to manipulate your data.

Comment: can you help me with code i am not good familiar with ajax and webservice

Comment: Take a look at my answer here, I go into detail about Client-Ajax-Server-Client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250608/how-do-you-keep-track-of-checkbox-changes-in-asp-net/32251158#32251158

Comment: i am not understanding it well can you help me